# WebSphere - dumps generation system signal vs server script

Tags: websphere, middleware, websphere-liberty, application-server

I am looking for an explanation in differences between methods generating thread and heap dumps.

What I know so far:

1. system signal eg. `kill -3` triggers instant creation of both (thread and heap dump)
2. script shipped with Liberty does run java agent which does magic and generates customizable output: thread dump alone or together with heap dump or core dump (or even with both)

`server javadump myserver --include=thread,heap,system`
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_server.html

..so my questions are:

- what's better and why?
- is there any difference in generated dumps?
- which one would you use for providing exposed and automated way of dumps creation (eg. for developers)?
- anyone has any experience with my previous point? I would highly appreciate your ProTips
- ..and also anything you might consider worth to mention here.

PS
What I've noticed. If I do system signal multiple times in a row nothing hangs and the number of generated dumps is equal to number of attempts made. The same happens if I do the same using script based solution (of course it takes longer).
..but if I do `kill -3 <PID> ; server javadump myserver --include=thread,heap` then server hungs and dumps are not generated - this state is unrecoverable without a restart. <- I've not spent much time on this behaviour so it could be just a failure unrelated to commands performed.

Thank you and best regards!